# Are there locations/altitudes with minimum speed requirements?

Tags: air-traffic-control, commercial-aviation, airspeed, commercial-operations

For example, a slower aircraft operating on the North Atlantic Track System would have an operational impact on surrounding/overtaking aircraft as well as potentially increasing ATC workload to ensure separation.

So, are there any formally encoded minimum aircraft speed/performance requirements based on operational environment?

(Maximum speeds are covered in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/are-there-limits-to-speeds-at-certain-altitudes) and the topic of *why* aircraft aren't designed to operate at slower airspeeds is covered in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/why-are-jet-aircraft-never-designed-with-a-slower-cruise-speed).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of any procedures or airways that require a minimum airspeed. Having a minimum climb gradient is quite common, typically on departure procedures to ensure terrain clearance.

It generally works out in such a way that aircraft with similar performance tend to cruise at the same levels. Most passenger jets cruising around 30,000-40,000 feet all happen to have a cruise speed of somewhere in the mach .75-.85 range. Slower turboprops often cruise at about 25,000 feet, and below that various GA planes. Granted, there can be quite a speed difference for those planes cruising at about 25,000 feet and below (for example, an [ATR 72](https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=AT72&ICAOFilter=at72) has a cruising speed of 275 KTAS, a [Dash 8 Q400](https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=DH8D&NameFilter=dash) is about 370 KTAS - they both commonly cruise at 25,000 feet). However, these levels are typically less crowded, so it is not so much of a problem. For the really crowded, higher levels, most aircraft have very similar performance.

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is you file your flight plan for the NAT with a proposed Mach #, but when you get your Oceanic Clearance they will assign Mach #s for each segment of the NAT and that's what you have to fly unless cleared for a different speed.  The adherence to assigned Mach #s are the only assurance of separation once out of radar coverage.

Perusing the [NAT Operations Manual](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/separation_standards/rvsm/documents/_Updated_NAT_Doc007_V-2017-1.pdf) I couldn't find anything that gives a minimum Mach #, but if you were unable or didn't want to maintain the Mach # assigned, you would probably be given the option of flying down below RVSM airspace, or taking an off-NAT routing like the northerly "Blue Spruce" route (which airplanes use when they have to stop in Iceland for fuel because they don't have the range for the NATs).

Comment: That's not actually a minimum speed limit, though. It's just an ATC instruction, just like ATC will often instruct aircraft to reduce speed during vectors for approach.